# H2 java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found

Tags: maven, ant, h2

Im trying to call the org.h2.tools.RunScript class from maven by calling an ANT script.

maven looks like ...

```
         <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.3</version>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <phase>validate</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>run</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                    <tasks>
            <property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
            <property name="runtime_classpath" refid="maven.runtime.classpath"/>
            <property name="test_classpath" refid="maven.test.classpath"/>
            <property name="plugin_classpath" refid="maven.plugin.classpath"/>

                        <echo>Starting DB</echo>
                        <ant antfile="${basedir}/dbbuild.xml" target="dbdo" />
                    </tasks>
               </configuration>
             </execution>
           </executions>
         </plugin>
```

the ant script looks like this:

```
<project name="" default="make" basedir=".">

<target name="make">

    <property value="." name="basedir" />
    <java classname="org.h2.tools.RunScript"
      fork="true"
      maxmemory="128m" >
    <arg line="-user " />
    <arg value=" sa" />  
    <arg line="-driver "/>
    <arg value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <arg line="-url " /> 
    <arg value=" &quot;jdbc:h2:file:${basedir}\\mydb;LOCK_MODE=3&quot;"/>
    <arg line="-script " />
    <arg value=" ${basedir}/src/main/resources/database/h2/testSchema.sql"/>

    <classpath>
      <pathelement path="${runtime_classpath}"/>
    </classpath>
  </java>                       


</target>

 </project>
```

and I keep getting this error:

```
 [java] Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver 
 found for jdbc:h2:file:C:\Apps\development\workspace\Phase3_1\directpay\quickpay
 \\mydb;LOCK_MODE=3
 [java]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
 [java]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
 [java]     at org.h2.tools.RunScript.process(RunScript.java:312)
 [java]     at org.h2.tools.RunScript.runTool(RunScript.java:140)
 [java]     at org.h2.tools.RunScript.main(RunScript.java:68)
 [java] Java Result: 1
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] --------------------
```

The h2-1.3.163.jar is in the classpath.  Any help would be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the URL be `jdbc:h2:c:\Apps\...` instead of `jdbc:h2:file:...`. You might also want to try `/` instead of `\` for the file path.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  Both good suggestions, but they didnt seem to make a difference separately or combined.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  The documentation for the RunScript calls for quotes around the url parameter...
[-help] or [-?]     Print the list of options
[-url "<url>"]      The database URL (jdbc:...)

I had escaped quot; on either side of the param, once I removed the quotes it worked fine.  I set the arg like:

```
    <arg line="-url" /> 
    <arg value="jdbc:h2:${basedir}\mydb;LOCK_MODE=3;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=3"/>
```